# Change SearchView little magnifier icon

Tags: android, searchview

I want to change the little magnifier icon that looks like an `EditText`'s `drawableLeft` on a `SearchView`.

I have tried the following:

[This link](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/search_view.xml#L85) shows the **layout xml** file for the whole Search Widget. So using this method (similar to reflection) I changed every icon **excepting the little magnifier one**:

```
int submitButtonId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_go_btn", null, null);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(submitButtonId);
imageView.setImageResource(submitIcon);
```

I tried changing both `android:id/search_mag_icon` and `android:id/search_button`, but the little magnifier inside the `EditText` is still gray (I just want a white one).

**Still not beating,** I proceed to make some hypothesis:

*Since it didn't work it must be both `ImageViews` (corresponding to `android:id/search_mag_icon` and `android:id/search_button`) Then it **must** mean the icon is either a **drawablePadding** **background** or **set up programatically**.
"There is no `android:drawableLeft` nor `android:drawableRight` in the layout file so the first option is wrong...*

Ergo, I proceed to confirm if it is indeed a [background](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/textfield_search_default_holo_dark.9.png). **NOPE**, the background just covers the blue lines.

So, if the little magnifier is **not** an `ImageView` **nor** a `drawableLeft/Right` **nor** a `background`, [It must have been set programmatically](https://cells-source.cs.columbia.edu/plugins/gitiles/platform/frameworks/support/+/android-4.3_r1/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.java#1582) (Look for the nested class `SearchAutoComplete`, **BUT NO!!!**

So, how do I change this little magnifier icon? I have literally tried everything

Answer (score 3):

Well this question took me about half an hour to write cause I wanted to rule out things I had already done, but I found the answer 5 mins after posting it: http://nlopez.io/how-to-style-the-actionbar-searchview-programmatically/

PS: yep, reflection all the way

Comment: It is indeed, make me wanna vomit. But literally there is no other way, API is private

Comment: Actually there is, as long as you've transitioned to material and appcompat v-21. SearchView is much better and styleable there. But I had to stick with the old SearchView, so your answer is perfect for me. Consider copying

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is having this issue, What worked for me was:

```
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); //This is what does the trick. Removing the magnifier icon.

    ImageView searchHintIcon = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_mag_icon);
    searchHintIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_search_black);
```

Here is the whole method:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.home_search, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search_action).getActionView();

    //If, this one returns null, use second option.
    SearchableInfo searchableInfo = searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName());
    if (searchableInfo == null) {
        searchableInfo = searchManager.getSearchableInfo(new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), SearchActivity.class));
    }
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchableInfo);
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    try {
        EditText searchEditText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
        searchEditText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        searchEditText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        ImageView searchHintIcon = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_mag_icon);
        searchHintIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_search_black);

        Field f = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(searchEditText, 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```